# run nodejs app in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-hosting

I have added firebase admin in my nodejs project. but not able to run the app after hosting in firebase.can anybody tell me how to run this or what is the issue.My firebase.json code:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./"
  }
}
```

i have given the below code in index.js

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./path to service account");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://<database>.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting to happen here.  You can't host your own node app with Firebase Hosting.  Firebase Hosting primarily serves just static web content.  There is one new feature that lets you proxy web requests to code deployed on Cloud Functions for Firebase, so you might want to look into that.

Comment: can you specify that new feature?

Comment: It's the Cloud Functions for Firebase integration with Hosting. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions